# Como contar registros de 3 tablas unidas por llave foránea

Tags: mysql

Tengo 3 tablas principales "rutina", "familia", "producto". Una rutina puede tener varias familias y varios productos, para ello tengo la tabla rutina_has_familia y rutina_has_producto, donde almaceno la relación con ambas llaves foráneas.

routine

[image: Tabla Rutina]

routine_has_family

[image: Tabla Rutina_has_family]

routine_has_product

[image: Tabla Rutina_has_product]

Necesito hacer una consulta donde se muestre toda la información de la rutina, agregándole 2 columnas donde cuente el número de familias y el número de productos que tiene.

He intentado con lo siguiente:

```
    SELECT routine.*,
COUNT(routine_has_family.FAMILY_idFamily) AS familys,
COUNT(routine_has_product.PRODUCT_idProduct) AS products
FROM routine 
LEFT JOIN routine_has_family ON routine.idRoutine = routine_has_family.ROUTINE_idRoutine 
LEFT JOIN routine_has_product ON routine.idRoutine = routine_has_product.ROUTINE_idRoutine 
GROUP BY routine.idRoutine
```

Arrojándome el siguiente resultado
[image: Imagen del primer intento]

El cual es erróneo, pues la rutina con id 2 tiene dos familias y dos productos

Si agrupo por otras columnas

```
    SELECT routine.*,
COUNT(routine_has_family.FAMILY_idFamily) AS familys,
COUNT(routine_has_product.PRODUCT_idProduct) AS products
FROM routine 
LEFT JOIN routine_has_family ON routine.idRoutine = routine_has_family.ROUTINE_idRoutine 
LEFT JOIN routine_has_product ON routine.idRoutine = routine_has_product.ROUTINE_idRoutine 
GROUP BY routine.idRoutine, routine_has_family.FAMILY_idFamily, routine_has_product.PRODUCT_idProduct
```

Me da el siguiente resultado

[image: Resultado 2]

El cual también es erróneo.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer la consulta?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar el conteo que deseas utilizando sub-consultas, y no *joins*. De esta manera, cada sub-consulta te entregará el resultado de relaciones que tiene con cada tabla por separado.

Intenta algo como:

```
select   routine.*
       , (select count(1) 
            from routine_has_family 
           where routine.idRoutine = routine_has_family.ROUTINE_idRoutine 
         ) family_count
       , (select count(1) 
            from routine_has_product  
           where routine.idRoutine = routine_has_product.ROUTINE_idRoutine 
         ) product_count
  from routine
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó esa consulta para este caso. Aunque me quedé con la duda sobre si se puede hacer con joins, pues al hacerlo con sólo dos tablas si funciona jeje pero se me complica cuando le agrego una más

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, no tiene sentido hacer la consulta con un solo join. Si lo que quieres conseguir es la cuenta de cada relación, esta es la ruta, recuerda que cada join es básicamente un producto cartesiano.